# Is SignalR connection id specific to one conversation or to one user?

Tags: c#, sql-server, signalr

I want to chat one-to-one and chat in a group in my app. I can implement one-to-one chatting by using IUserIdProvider interface. But when I search for group chatting, I can't see any ways of using user ID instead of connection ID.
I want to know whether SignalR connection ID is specific to one conversation or to one user so that I know how to implement group chatting.

Comment: every time a user connects to the server his connection id changes

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of ways to find connection ID from user name for example implement your own user ID to connection ID mapping structure and for group chatting you need to implement "subscriber publisher" pattern, whatever I suggest you to read this page on [asp.net](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

Comment: Yes, but I want to know whether SignalR creates a new connection ID when the user **starts a conversation** or **connect/login to the server**

Comment: *a new conversation